# Multiple NFT contract vs Single NFT Contract

Tags: solidity, nft, erc-1155

I was creating a place where people can launch their NFT projects. But there will be many NFT projects that will be coming in.

Is it okay to do just one NFT contract for different artist? Or we need 1:1 nft contract for each artist with different token ids?

Answer (score 0):

Have you read about any products in the NFT market?What they usually do is they give the user the option of choosing a platform-specific NFT contract, or you can choose to deploy a proprietary contract in which you create the NFT!What you need to know is that the latter usually costs a little more GAS, that's all.

Comment: Should not each artist have their own contract? I think thats the standard right

Comment: Of course you can!This is not a hassle, just a little more GAS when deploying the contract